# django httpresponse problem

Tags: django

my problem is when is leave my username and password field blank it shows the error
"(The view PatientInfo.views.login_check didn't return an HttpResponse object. ")

here im using login handler for my default login page and login_check when it will successfully login.
here on leaving username or password field blank its not return response.even i used HttpResponseRedirect as follows but its not working.

```
def login(request):

    template = "../templates/admin/login.html"
    data ={}
    return render_to_response( template, data, 
                              context_instance = RequestContext( request ) )


def login_check(request):

    user = request.POST['username']
    pas = request.POST['password']

    if (user is None or pas is None):
       if (user != "aa" and pas != "aa"):      

          return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')

    else:
        if (user == "aa" and pas =="aa"):
            template = "../templates/admin/index.html"
            data = {}
            return render_to_response( template, data, context_instance = RequestContext( request ) )
```

Comment: can you try to indent your code by four spaces when posting so that it displays in a readable way. If you're not sure whether it's correct check the preview.

Comment: You've posted the same question in a different guise 3 or 4 times. You still haven't taken the advise to use Django's login function which does exactly what you need which would make me suspect this is an assignment or something.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the condition whereby `user` is not `'aa'` or `pas` is not `'aa'`. Fill in the `else` clause with something useful.

Comment: yes i did user is not 'aa' or pas is not 'bb' actually im not gettin httpresponse it show error here... and also i used login_check handler in my login page html is goes to login_check handler and display my page which i want successfully when i give the username aa and password aa but the problem is on wrong username ,password it show httpresponse no object return error

Comment: Of course it does. You forgot to put something useful in the `else` clause.

Comment: def login_check(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
       user = request.POST['username']
       pas = request.POST['password']

    if (user is None or pas is None):
       if (user is not 'aa' and pas is not 'aa')        
           return render_to_response( template, data, 
                                  context_instance = RequestContext( request ) )

Comment: Your *other* else part. You know, the one that doesn't exist?

Comment: else:
        if (user == "aa" and pas =="aa"):
            template = "../templates/admin/index.html"
            data = {}
            return render_to_response( template, data, context_instance = RequestContext( request ) )

ACTUALLY i mention my code as above.. u plz go through it.. i hope u clear with my problem thanx in advance

Comment: I have already gone through the code. I have already told you what the problem is. Perhaps you have not gone through the code yet.

Comment: i go through with my code now and i submit u my else part it running successfully but this part i have posted dats not running def login_check(request): if request.method == "POST": user = request.POST['username'] pas = request.POST['password'] if (user is None or pas is None): if (user is not 'aa' and pas is not 'aa') return render_to_response( template, data, context_instance = RequestContext( request ) )

Comment: in this i check all condition here the problem is it shows doesnt return httpresponse object

Comment: can u help me.. im not gettin what wrong in this part                         def login_check(request): if request.method == "POST": user = request.POST['username'] pas = request.POST['password'] if (user is None or pas is None): if (user is not 'aa' and pas is not 'aa') return render_to_response( template, data, context_instance = RequestContext( request ) )